# ckeditor extraAllowedContent for viewhelper

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to allow content for my php FormViewHelper method ?
It looks like `@form('inputName')@`, which basically sets the value of the input field if given and form not successfully submitted yet.

I am writing a custom bootstrap form plugin for Ckeditor but of course the
`editor.insertHtml()` strips out these `@form()@` definitions.

Comment: what is there to downvote now ? can some of you geniuses tell me what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! Answers can take days. Be more patient. Meanwhile, be sure to read the documentation about this strange place. I am sure there is a lot to find out for you. Good luck!
P.S. The down vote is not gone. I gave you one up.  -1 + 1 = 0.Insulting the people will not motivate anybody to answer. Note that it is possible to delete one's own comments if need be.

Comment: well thanks. strange place true.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here is the answer:

editor.setMode('source');
editor.setData(html);

and all my nice little `@form()@` thingies are still there.